# Stopping more than one setInterval in same Function (NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, loops, setinterval

I'm attempting to cancel multiple timers - here's my code :

```
timer1 = setInterval(func1,3000)

stopper=999
count=5
function func1(){
    console.log("called func1 ")
    if(count<=0){           //Count check, if zero , stop looping
        clearInterval(timer1)
        clearInterval(timer2)
    }else{                  //if count bigger than 0
        timer2 = setInterval(func2,3000)
        function func2(){
            count=count-1
            console.log("Called Func2 " + stopper)
            stopper=count 
        }
    }
}
```

When `stopper` hits `0`, it stops writing "Called Func1", but it's still writing "Called Func2" over and over even if `stopper` is `-999` - how do I stop looping this double setInterval?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is every time func1 is called a new setInterval is being added to the stack.

One possible solution to this would be to replace setInterval for timer2 with setTimeout.

```
timer1 = setInterval(func1,3000)

stopper=999
count=5
function func1(){
    console.log("called func1 ")
    if(count<=0){           //Count check, if zero , stop looping
         clearInterval(timer1)
         clearTimeout(timer2)
    }else{                  //if count bigger than 0
         timer2 = setTimeout(func2,3000)
         function func2(){
             count=count-1
             console.log("Called Func2 " + stopper)
             stopper=count 
        }
    }
}
```

The second solution would be to clear the timer2 before setting a new one.

```
timer1 = setInterval(func1,3000)

stopper=999
count=5
function func1(){
    console.log("called func1 ")
    if(count<=0){           //Count check, if zero , stop looping
         clearInterval(timer1)
         clearInterval(timer2)
    }else{                  //if count bigger than 0
         timer2 = setInterval(func2,3000)
         function func2(){
             count=count-1
             console.log("Called Func2 " + stopper)
             stopper=count 
             clearInterval(timer2)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i really need the setinterval because i need the loops, but then ur 2nd answer is correct! thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the `timer2` is being overwritten every time by a new id of the `setInterval` call when the `setInterval(func2,3000)` is called from `func1`.

You are setting up a `setInterval` for `func1` in the beginning it schedules several `setInterval` calls for the `func2` in the `else` block. The `func1` is being invoked 5 times and a separate `setInterval` for the `func2` is setup for each `func1` call.

Now there are multiple intervals set-up for `func2` with multiple `ids` and each time this happens the `timer2` is overwritten with the latest value of the id.

So when the `count` reaches `0` it actually cancels one such interval id setup for `func2` and the others still continue to run.

You can maintain an array to capture the ids from the `setInterval` calls for `func2` and cancel them all when `count` reaches 0:

```js
(function(){
  const timer1 = setInterval(func1,3000)
  let stopper = 999
  let count = 5
  const timerIds = [];

  function func1(){
      console.log("called func1 ")
      if(count<=0){           //Count check, if zero , stop looping
          clearInterval(timer1);
          timerIds.forEach(id => clearInterval(id));
      }else{                  //if count bigger than 0
          timerIds.push(setInterval(func2,3000));
          function func2(){
              count = count - 1
              console.log("Called Func2 " + stopper)
              stopper = count 
          }
      }
}
})();
```